# Content Item with users and items in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I'm considering using Orchard CMS (1.5) as a backbone of my next application. What I will try to achieve is to create an Content Item called 'Account' that will represent a business account.

The challenge is that each account - content item will need to:

1. manage their own users
2. users can have parents - managers
3. have content items which are accessible only by users associated with that account

I couldn't find any projects out there that would implement such structure so I wondered if anyone here knows about anything like that or maybe articles that would help me get started. I understand that in 1.5 content item permissions are available but I have no idea how to start with points (1) and (2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an Account fits under the notion of a Content Item. What I would suggest is to develop your own module. Perhaps you can have a look at http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.Profile. This modules was developed on top of the Orchard.Users module that ships with Orchard. You can see how it makes use of Orchard.Users to provide more features. :)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't answer my question. In this case an 'Account' is a business entity which you could call customer for example. It is not authentication account and has nothing to do with profile.

In fact such customer should have the ability to manage their own users.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building application with this level of complexity, you should definitely look at skywalker's web shop series. It currently has 11 parts, starting from [here](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1).

I presume that the most interesting parts for you would be parts 8 ([Registering new Customer to the site](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-8)), 9 ([Creating Orders and Communicating with the PSP](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-9)) and 10 ([Managing the Customers and Orders from the backend](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-10)) where there are plenty examples of using Orchard architecture against your own, creating complex parent-child relationships (for example a Customer can have many Orders, while every Order can have multiple Order Items, and each Order Item consists of a Product or Bundles of Products) and handling them through administration by building your own admin menus with multiple tabs.

This series helped me a lot when I was building some of my own complex applications and I believe it would help you too if you're still considering Orchard for application development..